# What is wrong with this IO::Socket::UNIX example?

Tags: perl, io-socket

I am trying to implement a simple echo client/server, over a Unix socket. (My ultimate goal is to exchange JSON data, but this example is for simplicity). I have no idea why the client process disappears into a black hole when it tries to print to the socket the second time.

server.pl :

```
use IO::Socket::UNIX;

my $socket_path = '/tmp/mysocket';
unlink $socket_path if -e $socket_path;

my $socket = IO::Socket::UNIX->new(
    Local  => $socket_path,
    Type   => SOCK_STREAM,
    Listen => SOMAXCONN,
);

die "Can't create socket: $!" unless $socket;

while (1) {
    next unless my $connection = $socket->accept;
    chomp( my $line = <$connection> );
    print $connection "$line\n";
}
```

client.pl :

```
use IO::Socket::UNIX;

my $socket = IO::Socket::UNIX->new(
    Type => SOCK_STREAM,
    Peer => '/tmp/mysocket',
);

die "Can't create socket: $!" unless $socket;

my $line;

print $socket "one\n";
chomp( $line = <$socket> );
say $line;

print $socket "two\n";
chomp( $line = <$socket> );
say $line;

say "three";
```

Expected output:

```
> ./client.pl
> one
> two
> three
```

Actual output:

```
> ./client.pl
> one
```

Comment: would you give it a try with perl -w and put the output for us. maybe I might be able to help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You put the `$socket->accept` call inside your `while` loop. After your server establishes a connection and receives some input from the client, the next thing it wants to do is establish a new connection.

Move the `accept` call outside the `while` loop

```
my $connection = $socket->accept;
$connection->autoflush(1);
while (my $line = <$connection> ) {
    chomp($line);
    print $connection "$line\n";
}
```

or, if you do want to accept more than one connection,

```
while (1) {
    next unless my $connection = $socket->accept;
    $connection->autoflush(1);
    while (my $line = <$connection>) {
        chomp($line);
        print $connection "$line\n";
    }
}
```

Your current solution will also likely be "suffering from buffering", so both the server and the client should set `autoflush(1)` on their socket handlers.

Now to handle *simultaneous* connections, the server would usually call `fork` after getting a connection, and handling that connection in a child process.

```
while (1) {
    my $connection = $socket->accept;
    if (fork() == 0) {
        $connection->autoflush(1);
        while (my $line = <$connection>) {
            chomp($line);
            print $connection "$line\n";
        }
        close $connection;
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: The second idiom is the one I needed. Thank you. I think the server was not reading EOF from the client. As for _simultaneous_ connections, there will be thousands of clients connecting, but I prefer to keep it simple and let them queue, rather than forking more servers. Simple request/response, and no need for me to maintain state for each connection.

Answer (score 3):

A complete bi-directional example for anyone looking:

Server:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

use IO::Socket::UNIX qw( SOCK_STREAM SOMAXCONN );

my $SOCK_PATH = '/tmp/test.sock';
unlink($SOCK_PATH) if -e $SOCK_PATH;

my $server = IO::Socket::UNIX->new(
   Type => SOCK_STREAM(),
    Local => $SOCK_PATH,
   Listen => SOMAXCONN,
)
   or die("Can't create server socket: $!\n");

while (1) {
    my $connection = $server->accept;
    if (fork() == 0) {
        print "** New connection received **\n";
        $connection->autoflush(1);
        my $count = 1;
        while (my $line = <$connection>) {
            if ($line){
                chomp($line);
                $connection->print($count . ' -> ' . $line . "\n"); # Sent response back to client, \n terminates
                print "Received and replied to $count '$line'\n";
                $count++;
            }
        }
        close $connection;
        exit;
    }
}
```

Client:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

use IO::Socket::UNIX qw( SOCK_STREAM );

my $SOCK_PATH = '/tmp/test.sock';

my $client = IO::Socket::UNIX->new(
   Type => SOCK_STREAM(),
   Peer => $SOCK_PATH
)
   or die("Can't connect to server: $!\n");

$client->autoflush(1);


## Listen for replies
if (fork() == 0) {
    while (my $line = <$client>) {
        if ($line){
            chomp($line);
            print("Recv: '" . $line . "'\n");
        }
    }
}

## Send something
for my $itm ('Alpha','Beta','Gamma','Delta'){
    print("Send: " . $itm . "\n");
    print($client $itm . "\n") or warn("Can't send: $!\n"); # send to server, \n terminates
}

print "** Client Finished **\n";
```